# Data driven testing using csv in Protractor

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, protractor, data-driven

I am trying to run data-driven testing using csv file in protractor:

**I have created a read csv promise module:**

```javascript
    let readSync = async function (path1) {
    console.log(path1)
      const csv = require('csv-parser')
      const fs = require('fs')
      const results = [];
    
    
      function getIdRequest(path2) {
        console.log(path2)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
         
          fs.createReadStream(path2)
            .pipe(csv(path2))
            .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
            .on('end', () => {
              resolve(results);
            })
        });
      }
      console.log(path1)
      return getIdRequest(path1);
    }
    // to get the request body 
    
      module.exports = readSync;
```

**Now i am calling the same from my test file:**

```javascript
    let readCSV = require('../commons/readSync.js');
    
    describe('Validate stage 1 behaviour', function () {
    
      let testdata=await readCSV(browser.params.testFile);
    
      for (let a of testdata) {
     
        it('test {Regression} {Sanity} {Sanity}', async function () {
          //check title
          console.log("inside")
          await mainPage.goto();
          await mainPage.clickElement('inputField')
```

**But i cannot use await inside describe, so I tried using :**

```javascript
    let readCSV = require('../commons/readSync.js');   
    
    describe('Validate stage 1 behaviour', function () {
    
      readCSV(browser.params.testFile).then(function(testdata){
    
      for (let a of testdata) {
        console.log("outside")
        it('test {Regression} {Sanity} {Sanity}', async function () {
          //check title
          console.log("inside")
        });
    
      }
```

but in this,  'it' function is not getting executed, its printing only 'outside'

**Challenges**

1. Cannot use await inside describe as it accepts only synchronous function
2. Cannot use `promise.then(describe(function(){}` because 'IT' and 'Describe' is not recognized when called inside the callback. I get 0 spec executed message.
3. Tried calling the **testdata** in before hooks but this also fails as the for loop is outside the It block . So, the compiler tries to run for loop even before 'before hook' is executed .
4. I tried using nested describe and calling await testdata in before each and before all . But even that fails with the same reason , refer:
   https://stackoverflow.com/q/48344674/6793637

**Questions:**

1. So is there a better way to run data driven testing using csv in
   protractor ?
2. Is there a way to synchronously make the suggest solution work?
3. Why is describe or IT block doesn't work inside a callback ? Eg Promise.then(describe()) won't execute describe

Comment: It seems like you're really asking how to synchronously read a file, which isn't a testing or QA issue. fs has a blocking method: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

Comment: @jonrsharpe hi the question is more about how to do data driven testing in protractor. I have updated my question thanks for reviewing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519037/is-data-driven-testing-possible-with-protractor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi i found another csv module : csv-parse : https://csv.js.org/parse/ (Its used in postman)

```
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');
```

Use this module for data-driven testing instead of below-step

**Below method is deprecated:**

Made it work.

Please suggest any better ways if anyone knows:

**Solution:**

**Install system-sleep module:**

```
npm install system-sleep
```

**.............Updated..........**

**Now run your tests as:**

```
let testdata=readSync(browser.params.testFile);
var sleep = require('system-sleep');

describe('Validate dfsfdsf 1 behaviour', function () {

//Assign the value when promise gets resolved
//This is asynchronous so we will add a implicit wait
testdata.then(function(b){testdata=b}); 

//sleep till the test resolves
  while(typeof testdata.then === 'function'){
    sleep(1)
  }     

  for(let a of testdata){
    it('test {Regression} {Sanity} {Sanity}', async function () {
      console.log(a)
    });
  }
```

> **Update:**
>
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser-sync-plus-promise
>
> Happy days guys I have created an npm package for this, anyone is free
>   to use it

**Now data driven testing is as simple as :**

```
let parser= require('csv-parser-sync-plus-promise');
let testdata = parser.readCsvSync(browser.params.testFile);



describe('Validate dfsfdsf 1 behaviour', function () {


  for(let a of testdata){
    it('test {Regression} {Sanity} {Sanity}', async function () {
      console.log(await parser.readCsvPromise(browser.params.testFile))
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sleep should never the solution, why not: `testdata.then(function(b){ for(let a of b){ // code here}});`

Comment: Or use async/await

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal he please see my question , I tried that , but it and describe block is not being identified inside callback function

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal async doesn't work inside describe . Describe block supports only synchronous function . I can't keep it inside before hooks also because the for loop is outside the 'it' block and so will get executed before the 'before' hook  get executed

Comment: Your example is missing async on the describe function, e.g. `describe('Test Suite 1', async function(){
  let testdata = await asyncMethod()`

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal hi I think you are missing the fact that await works only inside async functions and describe doesn't support async

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal this throws error saying describe expected function but got async function

Comment: I think you are right, was looking at the wrong docs. I think you could make a `before` use async.

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal tried that also , please see the updated question :) .

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach using map function:
(Considering testArray is an array of objects)

```
var testParams =testConfig.testArray;   
testParams.map(function(testdata) { 

   it('write your test here', function() { 
         console.log('Username: ',         
          testData.username); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi the issues here is of getting the test array :) , if we get an array , then map or for or while any loop works .but the csv parse returns  a promise that resolves to a array